# Oracle in-line view metadata?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle19c

Is it possible to get a list of columns with their data types for an inline view?
I have a group that is storing variables and their values as an inline view at the top of a canned SQL script to drive some reports

```
With params As
(
   "Annual Accounting Report" report_name
  ,"Jim Jones"                report_recipient
  ,"Cxx005169"                report_ticket
  ,"Eastern"                  region
  <<lots of other standard and custom one-off name value pairs>>
 );
```

The above *params* inline view contains a mix of standard name value pairs as one-off custom pairs that a report writer can add as needed. The rest of the report SQL code consists of a long chain of other inline views that CROSS JOIN the *params* inline view to access these values. For example,

```
,my_report_view AS
(
 Select ColA from stuff Cross Join params Where stuff.region = params.region 
)
Select * from my_report_view;
```

I would like to replace the long chain of in-line views into isolated functions to make the whole thing more modular. Ideally I would like to pass the entire contents of *params* to each replacement function as an object, *params-object*. Instead of a wide record the *params-object* would be nested table (I think). Using the *params-object* nested table the functions should be able to pick the parameters they need from the is input object and ignore the rest.

The challenge is I want to create this new *params-object* from the existing in-line *params* view. My reasoning is that leaving the existing structure in place will cause less disruption initially as I slowly guide them to a more modular frame of mind. Essentially, leave the *params* in-line view in place for now and sneakily transform it into a *params-object* for use by functions.

Doing this sneaky magic would require me to not only unpivot the in-line view which is not hard but do so dynamically which is hard. Why dynamically? Because report writers are used to adding custom one-off name value pairs to the *params* in-line view whenever they need to do some customization. I would like to be able to handle this gracefully and avoid forcing the report writers to add a line to the unpivot statement every time they add a new name-value pair.

Any ideas? I already checked *user_tab_columns*. It does not contain meta data on in-line views.

Comment: Could you paste a valid Oracle 19c SQL example? The WITH statement above just throws errors for me. Maybe edit it so that it would run.

Comment: The code provided is notional / pseudo / partial example to illustrate my design question. It's not for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this will really help but the dump() function gives you a type:

```
SQL> With params As
  2  (
  3  select
  4     'Annual Accounting Report' report_name
  5    ,'Jim Jones'                report_recipient
  6    ,'Cxx005169'                report_ticket
  7    ,'Eastern'                  region
  8    from dual)
  9  select dump(report_name) from params;

DUMP(REPORT_NAME)                                                               
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Typ=96 Len=24: 65,110,110,117,97,108,32,65,99,99,111,117,110,116,105,110,103,32,
82,101,112,111,114,116
```

Comment: Interesting but it doesn't look like that will work outside of SQL*Plus which is a non-starter.

Comment: @KevinWhite, dump is a SQL function, it works in any client. But it doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: Ah! So it is but yeah that is just not quite right. Good idea though @Bobby. I am sure Dump will come in handy some other desperate day.

Comment: Another idea I used a long time ago is to actually materialized that CTE into an actual view. Then, retrieving the view metadata is trivial.